# MVC C# activation url redirects to other path

Tags: url, model-view-controller, query-string, account, url-scheme

I have code that i used a year or two ago to create an activation link that is send by email, using a code as a parameter, i tried so many different ways, encoding, using other syntax, adding web.config settings `<pages validateRequest="false" />
requestValidationMode="2.0"`
, annotations `[AllowHtml]`, literally tried dozen of post on the internet but none of them worked.

So i am overseeing something here, that i am sure but i can't find the solution.

**The error i get is:**
    A potentially dangerous Request.Path value was detected from the client (?)

The format i use is

`Url.Action("action","controller", new { Id = guidValue }, Request.Url.Scheme)`

My routing is the Default so this should work.

**The Url is like this in the address bar once clicked:**

```
http://localhost:52641/Account/Login?ReturnUrl=%2FAccount%2FAccountActivation%2F%3Fid%3Dfc39f53f-6fa7-43d2-b30a-8b4e20f0f237
```

**While it should give me:**

```
http://localhost:52641/Account/AccountActivation?id=fc39f53f-6fa7-43d2-b30a-8b4e20f0f237
```

**What is happening here?**
Thank you for any feedback!

Comment: Did you try disable simple membership i.e. using `<add key="enableSimpleMembership" value="false"/>` or `<add key="autoFormsAuthentication" value="false" />` (and setting redirect URL to your own)? The problem seem coming from simple membership's auth system which opted default redirect URL.

Comment: Will try this tonight and post back results here, thank you Tetsuya for the suggestion!

Comment: @TetsuyaYamamoto, tried your suggestion but this keeps getting me to the Login action however your remark made me think, and since i am not using the auth system (for this case) i removed it and well it works now. With the auth system i needed to use the UserId & Code  parameters in the Url.Action(... {UserId = xxx , code = xxx}  ...) which worked ...  THANK YOU! Feel free to elaborate in a answer if you like, it would help me understand more about the built in auth and membership.

Comment: @TetsuyaYamamoto, if you are willing and didn't do it yet, feel free to suggest what you think would be appropiated to do in my other post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54589272/cant-find-best-way-of-achieving-this-scenario  Thank you again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I removed the complete built in Authentication (NuGet packages & classes)
from my solution (since i didn't needed them) and this made the above case work as it was. I can't elaborate more on the what's and how's (i am sure other people can) but i think it has to do with routing that comes with the authentication.