# MVC Not able to redirect to custom login url

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, forms-authentication

I have set the following forms authentication attributes on web.config.

```
 <authentication mode="Forms" >
  <forms loginUrl="~/Account/VerifyCode" timeout="2880">
    <credentials passwordFormat="Clear">
      <user name="admin" password="admin"/>
    </credentials>
  </forms>
</authentication>
```

But always when navigate to a controller that is decorated with [Authorize] attribute,I am always redirected to ~/Account/Login?ReturnUrl=%2FProduct%2FCreate , instead of the the method I set in web.config (means VerifyCode).

Anyone has any idea why this is like this, and how to make it redirected to the method I specified in web.config?

Comment: Do you use any other type of Authentication aka Owin OAuth and so on? (See my previous similar issue: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54587860/mvc-c-sharp-activation-url-redirects-to-other-path)

Comment: Thanks  Lankymart. As mentioned in the link, this one helped : "when using the new OWIN forms authentication (as opposed to the old ASP.NET forms authentication), this gets set in the Startup class. In the default templates, it's in App_Start/Startup.Auth.cs in the ConfigureAuth method:"

Answer (score 0):

Try bellow code instead of your code

```
<authentication mode="Forms">
  <forms loginUrl="~/Account/VerifyCode" timeout="2880"/>
 </authentication>
```

Comment: Did n't work. It is still redirecting to ~Account/Login